# Female 4 pin fan header

Tags: pwm, fan, header

While male 4 pin fan headers are plentiful ([e.g., here](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Wire-To-Board-Wire-To-Wire-Connector_MOLEX_47053-1000_MOLEX-47053-1000_C240840.html)), I can't find a female version of it. I see lots of them on fan extension cables, but none that can be soldered to a PCB. Does anyone know a type number or some information to continue my search?

I guess I could use standard 4 pin square headers without the tab, but I prefer to use the 'official' Molex connector to prevent myself from applying 12V to the 5V tach line and for a more secure fit.

Thank you very much.

Comment: These are meant for board-to-wire connections, I don't think you will find a board mountable female connector for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general method for finding mating parts for Molex connectors.

1. Go to the Molex site and search for the Molex part number,
   which is the manufacturer part number (`mfr. part #` for short)
   In your case it's `47053-1000`.
2. You'll get the product page.
   [This page](https://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0470531000_PCB_HEADERS.xml) in your case.
   Find the section called "mates with".

> I see lots of them on fan extension cables, but none that can be soldered to a PCB. Does anyone know a type number or some information to continue my search?

In our case, there are only wire-mounted housings that mate with that type of header.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of connector series/classes.
Some are wire to wire(w2w) connectors, some wire to board(w2b) connectors and some board to board(mezzanine) connectors. Only a few are capable of both(w2b,w2w). In this case you should look for some wire to wire connectors and crimp your cables yourself.